# Find a table with a column name matching a given pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, relational-database, introspection

This might sound a bit un-realistic, but I've recently had to study the database structure of a system am maintaining remotely, and it hit me that there were some occassions when I wanted to find all columns that were linked to a given table (see, the original devs didn't create explicit relations, but instead have relations encoded in the column names!).

For example, assuming all columns referring to a column `parent.parent` have the form `table.somefield_parent` as the means of documenting a relationship between the two fields, how do I find all such relationships (and the tables involved) using say the standard SQL commands / in-built functions?

Any solutions for MySQL or PostgreSQL are welcome.

NOTE :

- am not looking for patterns in the data, but in the meta-data.
- I know I can dump the db structure and search for the results there, but I don't want to go out of the db-shell to find these relationships (assume am working in say psql, and don't want to exit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **PostgreSQL** you can query the system catalog tables.

You can also query the information_schema, which consists of views providing the standard SQL way of displaying the information. Querying the system catalogs is usually much faster, though.

To find the children of one particular `parent` column:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
     , c.relname AS table_name
     , a.attname AS column_name
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  a.attname ~~ E'%\\_parent'
AND    NOT a.attisdropped
AND    c.relkind = 'r'
AND    nspname !~~ E'pg\\_%';
```

To find **all** related column according to the description:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS parrent_schema
     , c.relname AS parrent_table
     , a.attname AS parrent_column
     , n1.nspname AS child_schema
     , c1.relname AS child_table
     , a1.attname AS child_column
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a1 ON a.attname = substring(a1.attname, '_(.*?)$')
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class c1 ON c1.oid = a1.attrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n1 ON n1.oid = c1.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
AND    c1.relkind = 'r'
AND    n.nspname !~~ E'pg\\_%'
AND    n1.nspname !~~ E'pg\\_%'
AND    NOT a.attisdropped
AND    NOT a1.attisdropped
-- AND    n.nspname = 'public'   -- to narrow it down to a specific schema
-- AND    n1.nspname = 'public'   -- to narrow it down to a specific schema
ORDER  BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

This assumes that the parrent columns don't have `_` in the name.
The key element is the join condition:

```
a.attname = substring(a1.attname, '_(.*?)$')
```

Answer (score 7):

Try querying the `information_schema.columns` view. It works in MySQL, but I have not tried it in Postgres. The `information_schema` schema is part of the ANSI SQL standard, so Postgres will quite probably have it as well.

Other views in `information_schema` include `information_schema.tables`, which is useful as well

Comment: I did something like `select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where column_name like '%_parent' and table_catalog='sat';`, and it solved my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL you can use the database information_schema for that. This database contains all the meta-data for the databases on that server. As far as I know every database user has to have access to that database.